# brew doctor returns not a valid keg (Trying to uninstall liberica-jdk-8-full installed via homebrew)

Tags: homebrew

I was trying to install autopsy using this guide
https://slo-sleuth.github.io/tools/InstallingAutopsyOnMacOS.html which I couldn't get it to work. So I have decided to uninstall and find something else to work with.

Kindly advise how can I uninstall liberica-jdk-8-full? I have ran brew doctor and below is the error I get.

```
Error: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/liberica-jdk-8-full.jdk/Contents/Home is not a valid keg
```

Comment: I have the same exact issue, also with liberica-jdk-8-full. [Opened an issue](https://github.com/bell-sw/homebrew-liberica/issues/24#issue-848786723) on the homebrew-liberica repo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I was able to fix my issue!! ([related s/o link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61164725/))

1. Remove `liberica-jdk8-full` from `/usr/local/Caskroom`
2. Remove `liberica-jdk-8-full.jdk` from `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`
3. Run `brew cleanup` to remove the broken symlink `/usr/local/opt/openjdk`